# Find outermost cordinates from Geodjango queryset which has point column

Tags: django, geolocation, geodjango

I am quite new to geographic data and geodjango itself. Let's say I have model:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    location = PointField()
```

I want to show map using `leafletjs` like this http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start-example.html with employee name and marker on their location.

Now say employees are all over Germany, but some of them work remotely and are located to some yet unknown location. If they were only located in Germany, I could display map of whole Germany and add marker based on coordinates. The problem is if one employee is based in Russia, I need to display Russia and so on for all other countries/employees.

To come back to code example:

If my `Employee` model queryset returns three employees based in two countries Germany and Russia, I want to display map of Germany to Russia with marker, not map of whole world. How do I calculate this outermost coordinates from queryset? Or what could be other approaches to solve above problem?

Comment: Russia is a huge, huge country do you want to show russia and germany in their entirity? That would make the map zoomed out to a great extent? Why not just use the best fitting box?

Comment: Best fitting box is what I am looking for indeed. But looks like I don't have to worry to find it myself, leafletjs seem to handle itself. I will update how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaflet should be able to calculate the bounding box for the map based on the points that you wish to display on it. This can be done quite easily `geodjango` as well. [extent](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#extent) is what you are looking for.

```
 bounds = Employee.objects.filter(some filter).extent()
```

This is deprecated in new version, instead use:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models import Extent
bounds = Employee.objects.filter(some filter).aggregate(Extent('point'))['point__extent']
```

In LefletJS:

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').fitBounds(51.505, 51.507], [51.56, 50.98]], {padding: [10, 10]});
```

Comment: glad to have helped